# Basic terminal question --> how to execute commands

Tags: terminal

I have a very silly question about the terminal. I am following a React tutorial and I am trying to set up a few things in the vscode terminal. Below you can find a screenshot of my terminal. I would like to run some more things, however, my name is not displaying and I don't know how to get it back. In other words, which command do I use to get back 'Name-air:~name$'? [image]

Even though this is quite a noob question, an answer would really help me out:). thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://carldesouza.com/how-to-stop-a-react-app-from-running-in-windows/
you can simply enter ctrl+C and it will prompt you with terminate job y/n type y and it will terminate the program

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't want to terminate the program, I would like execute additional commands.